# How can orders be cancelled and refunded using the Shopify API?

Tags: php, curl, shopify

I have been trying to cancel and refund one of my orders using shopify API in php.
When i send a curl request to Shopify API, its response is blank.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://3de0c1f89e936d4f52b29aXXXXXXX:8ae242d39b8fde6b0f8fe04fXXXXXXXX@ABC-XYZ.myshopify.com/admin/orders/145785434/cancel.json?amount=45.5");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

what is that i am missing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with the code. It's a problem with the address you're trying to access (or anything inbetween). You need to debug the problem yourself. First of all, enable the header output and have a look at the response you're receiving.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Echo out the data you receive before you pass it to the JSON decoder to see if it's corrupt or blank.

```
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **cancel** Shopify API function should sent by POST method.
[image]

I share the code I used to cancel orders:

```
    $url = "https://API_KEY:API_PASS@YOUR_SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/orders/$orderId/cancel.json";
            
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->reason = 'declined';

    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    
    //Set the URL that you want to GET by using the CURLOPT_URL option.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json'
    ));
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    //Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so that the content is returned as a variable.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //additional options
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true to follow redirects.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    //Execute the request.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

If you want to send more params, add them into **$data** variable. Example:

```
$data->amount = '45.5';
$data->currency = 'USD';
```

Check that currency is a field required when amount its sent. See more at [Shopify Orders API Docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2021-01)